# ebay api feed uploadfile can't success, error info: failureCount 1 LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS

Tags: php, ebay-api

eBay API feed revise inventory.

Right  revise inventory XML is what?

I use other people's code.

return

```
{
    "taskId": "task-12-13101609816",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "feedType": "LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS",
    "creationDate": "2023-05-28T04:13:07.000Z",
    "completionDate": "2023-05-28T04:17:57.000Z",
    "uploadSummary": {
        "successCount": 0,
        "failureCount": 1
    }
}
```

This XML return:

```
"status": "FAILED"

{
    "taskId": "task-12-1199504589",
    "status": "FAILED",
    "feedType": "LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS",
    "creationDate": "2023-05-27T10:59:47.000Z",
    "completionDate": "2023-05-27T11:02:46.000Z",
    "uploadSummary": {
        "successCount": 0,
        "failureCount": 0
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Header>
        <Version>685</Version>
        <SiteID>0</SiteID>
    </Header>
    <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
        <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
        <MessageID>test-1111</MessageID>
        <Version>637</Version>
        <InventoryStatus ComplexType="InventoryStatusType">
            <SKU>test-2222</SKU>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        </InventoryStatus>
    </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

```
return 
{
    "taskId": "task-12-13101609816",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "feedType": "LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS",
    "creationDate": "2023-05-28T04:13:07.000Z",
    "completionDate": "2023-05-28T04:17:57.000Z",
    "uploadSummary": {
        "successCount": 0,
        "failureCount": 1
    }
}
```

=====================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Header xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <SiteID>0</SiteID>
        <Version>951</Version>
    </Header>
    <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <Version>951</Version>
        <InventoryStatus ComplexType="InventoryStatusType">
            <SKU>SY0195GY</SKU> 
            <Quantity>7</Quantity>
        </InventoryStatus>
    </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

return

```
{
    "taskId": "task-12-13101609816",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "feedType": "LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS",
    "creationDate": "2023-05-28T04:13:07.000Z",
    "completionDate": "2023-05-28T04:17:57.000Z",
    "uploadSummary": {
        "successCount": 0,
        "failureCount": 1
    }
}
```

=================================================

Code is this.

## CREATE TASK

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
  "schemaVersion": "1149",
  "feedType": "LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS"
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer v^1.1#i^1#p^3#I^*****YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN HERE****py9v3J3ALc5rcFAAA',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY_GB'
  ),
));
```

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

## UPLOAD FILE

### test.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>v1............</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <InventoryStatus>
    <SKU>test-1111</SKU>
    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
  </InventoryStatus>
  <InventoryStatus>
    <SKU>test-2222</SKU>
    <Quantity>20</Quantity>
  </InventoryStatus>
</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
```

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1127376027/upload_file',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('fileName' => 'test.xml','file'=> new CURLFILE('/F:/test.xml'),'type' => 'form-data'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer v^1.1#i^1#p^3#I^*****YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN HERE****py9v3J3ALc5rcFAAA',
    'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY_GB',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

## GETTASK

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1127376027',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer v^1.1#i^1#p^3#I^*****YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN HERE****py9v3J3ALc5rcFAAA',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Ebay API feed revise inventory

Right  revise inventory XML is what?